# ASP.NET Page life cycle: methods vs Events

Tags: asp.net, events, methods, page-lifecycle

Can someone please explain to me the difference between methods and events in the ASP.NET page life cycle?

Comment: MSDN has a great breakdown of it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#additional_page_life_cycle_considerations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a page runs a series of methods are executed. These methods in turn raise events that can be handled by the user to perform various tasks like initializing controls, populating control properties, executing control behavioral code, etc.

Here is an excellent flowchart from MSDN that shows the different methods that are executed, and the events that are raised from those methods:

[image]

For more information about the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle, see the full overview on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: You can completely override the methods but you also have to call the base method. With Events such as Page_PreRender you don't. So why use one over the other?

Comment: For the most part, the methods just wrap the event calls, so it comes down to whether you need to do your work before or after the event is called.