# Control cannot override Page_Load in hierarchy

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, user-controls

A **ChildClass** user control I'm working with has a chain of parent classes, ultimately inheriting from **System.Web.UI.UserControl**.

```
public BasestClass : AnotherClassExtendingUserControl
{
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}

public BaseClass : BasestClass
{
    // no Page_Load
}
```

Two parent classes up the chain, Page_Load is marked *private*. The 'middle' class obviously doesn't override it, but I need to add something to the Page_Load of the **ChildClass** user control.

```
public ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    // think I need to override Page_Load here,
    // but there is no acceptable method to override
}
```

What can I do to get into the Page_Load of **ChildClass**? There are controls in that control that I need to manipulate that do not exist in **BaseClass** or **BasestClass**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Page_Load` (or `Load`) event  gets raised during execution of the `OnLoad` event method, so I would suggest moving your logic there. You shouldn't have a problem overriding the `OnLoad` method from your child class.

Comment: Not quite right. `Page_Load` is not an event, it's the default event handler for the `Load` event. I think using both an override of OnLoad and Page_Load might lead to confusion later on, especially if a class comes along that inherits from `ChildClass`. Event handlers are auto-wired up by default, whereas you have to explicitly call `base.OnLoad(e)` each time you override `OnLoad`. That's just my 2 cents.

Comment: @mafue: `OnLoad` is the page method that raises the `Load` event. The correct approach in this case is to override the event raiser, not the event handler. See here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: @mafue: Also see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664969/asp-net-page-life-cycle-methods-vs-events

Comment: Neither of those links say that Page_Load is an event. That's because it isn't :)

Comment: It does actually say just that. The diagram clearly shows the "Page Events" in the second column, in red. The `OnLoad` method raises the `Load` event, and `Page_Load` handles the event. I'm not looking to argue with you, but your comment was incorrect, and it could confuse someone.

Comment: @mafue: See my previous comment. Also, maybe this will clear things up for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It's perfectly clear, thanks. Read your answer, then read my comment again. There is no `Page_Load` event. There is a `Load` event and a `Page_Load` event handler. You are right when you say this "Page_Load handles the event," you are wrong when you say this: "The Page_Load event gets fired..."

Comment: @mafue: You realize that you're arguing pure semantics at this point, right? The event and the handler are intrinsically tied together and are for the most part synonymous when speaking informally, as most people will know what you're talking about when you refer to the handler of a specific event. You can test this by Googling `ASP.NET Page_Load Event` - you'll see that it's referred to as an event as often as it's referred to as an event handler. It appears as though OP understood what I was saying, which is what really matters to me.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your classes and just changed two things:

```
BasestClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

That shouldn't alter anything, since you said that `BasestClass` ultimately inherits from `UserControl`.

I also added this to BasestClass.Page_Load:

```
Response.Write("BasePage_Load");
```

Now, to solve your problem:

You can add a constructor to ChildClass and add an event handler for the Load event.

```
public ChildClass()
{
        Load += new EventHandler(_Default_Load);
}

void _Default_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Write("Event Handler");
}
```

You can also override OnPreRender:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
       base.OnPreRender(e);
       Response.Write("OnPreRender");
}
```

Doing all of the above, this is output in the response:

```
Event Handler
BasePage_Load
OnPreRender
```

If you want to be sure that the `Page_Load` method of `BasestClass` has already run before your new code, `OnPreRender` is the place to do your thing.